# Ignore css rule value

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a css file with the following content:

```
p {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div p {
    color: $paragraphColor;
    border: $paragraphBorder;   
}
```

I can inject a value into the file with replace that will override the default rule (red color or red border). Is there a value I can enter in place of $paragraphColor and $paragraphBorder that will make this rule ignored and the paragraph will be red or have a red border? Of course, I can set a wrong rule, e.g. color: ggggggggggg; but I don't want to enter the wrong rule.

EDIT:
I figured that the parameter could be property + value, for example:

```
div p {
    /* paragraph.color */
    /* paragraph.border */ 
}
```

then css file is correct and I get default values if non of them is replaced

Comment: Are you trying to override the `div p` with the `p` example? If so just add the `!important` flag is one way. Or are you trying to override the `p` with the `div p` css? It's a little unclear, but either way programmatically change the css probably isn't ideal.

Comment: No, the other way round: $paragraphColor should override paragraph color or do nothing, depends on $paragraphColor value.

Comment: What if you set `$paragraphColor` to `red`? In the end you probably know the color that you want, just set `$paragraphColor` to it and your problem is gone.

Comment: I don`t know that default color is red. I figured out some way and wrote it in above post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
color: unset !important;
```

Comment: When I use color: unset !important; then paragraph goes black but I want it red. I checked initial, inherit, revert too. It works only if I use unproper value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, i understood your question.
But i found this:

```
div p -> div.p
```

and you can set a `style=` to you HTML element, like:

```
<div style=width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;></div>
```

If you wanted to ask something else, and my question doesn't help me, then please write me a commentar.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: It should work, but I want to separate css frm html and try to avoid inject inline styles, specially when html is in many angular components. Finally I use my proposition from first post